# Pass Google Analytics Data into iFrame (we control both the domains)

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

Currently we have a page laid out like this:

Page on Domain A contains an iFrame with Domain B inside it.

These are both our domains and we are using the same Google Tag Manager/Google Analytics code on both domains.  How do I track traffic data into the iFrame from the parent page, so it does not display as "direct" and I can see all the correct information.

It is very important for me to be able to see the parent URL which is hosting the iFrame.

I do not think this is a duplicate question because we control both domains.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using classic GA or UA? If the latter, then you may need to adjust your tracker's cookie domain to NOT be auto, and also make sure you don't have the iframe domain in the referral exclusion list so that traffic moving from one domain to another would be considered as "referral".

Comment: This sounds like you want to configure your domains for cross domain tracking. There is a part in the docs that deals with iframes: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the parent page URL to the Querystring for the embedded iFrame.  So if the iFrame URL is current "http://myiframedomain.com/page1.html" it would become "http://myiframedomain.com/page1.html?embeddedIn=http%3A%2F%2Fmyparentdomain.com%2Fpagewithiframe.html"

On the pages within the iFrame you could read this data with either server side code or javascript and pass it to analytics.

In order to set the referrer manually in GA, you could use `_gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride','http://myparentdomain.com/pagewithiframe.html']);`

For more on manually controlling referrers with GA, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setReferrerOverride